# DNS Equivalent of Hosts file alias

Tags: dns

Two part question:

1)  In DNS, how do you replicate the effect of an alias in your host file?

2)  Is there a way to have a space in the alias?

Comment: 1) cname 2) no spaces in a hostname

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It's hard to say what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

a DNS alias is called a CNAME record, and is defined like

```
www        IN      CNAME  server1
```

in your zone file where server1 is a A record hostname within the zone, and www is the alias. No, Spaces may not be present in DNS Records.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/cname.html